# What it means "binary tree with pre-, post-, and in-order numbers assigned to the nodes"?

Tags: binary-tree

So, my questions comes from a exercise of the book "Open Data Structures":

"Suppose we are given a binary tree with pre-, post-, and
in-order numbers assigned to the nodes. Show how these numbers can be
used to answer each of the following questions in constant time:".

and i need to this exercise: "Given a node u, determine the depth of u"

Can someone explain what this means "Suppose we are given a binary tree with pre-, post-, and
in-order numbers assigned to the nodes" ( or with a example ) and give a hint to do the exercise?

Comment: Perform a pre-order search. The first item you find, assign the number 1. The second item you find, assign the number 2. etc.

Comment: I´ve tried with that but cant get anything. For example of we have 8 3 2 1 6 5 4 7 the order of pre than we assign 8 to index 1, 3 to index 2 and so on, rigth? I tried using this order and get the post order and then i get the post order in the sequence of index. With this i still cant find a solution. Can u give me another hint? And thx for the response!!

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention you @RaymondChen